# PHP numbers logic

Tags: php

I just started to learn PHP deeper for Zend PHP certification and I found this code, which actually works. Can someone explain me the logic behind this?

```
<?php
$num = 20% - 8;
echo $num; // 4
```

Comment: % is not per cent, but modulus, cf. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is the modulus operator, which in essence asks "*What is the remainder of 20 divided by -8*".

So you might ask, why isn't it *negative* 4? From the manual,

> The result of the modulo operator `%` has the same sign as the dividend — that is, the result of `$a % $b` will have the same sign as `$a`.

See the [PHP: Arithmetic Operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) for more documentation.

Answer (score 1):

% is not per cent, but modulus, cf. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic

20 = 2 * 8 + 4, therefore, 20 % 8 = 4